# I have added fingerprint on firebase project setting debug as well as playconsole but the Phone Authentication not working how to fix this?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have added fingerprint on firebase project setting debug as well as playconsole but the Phone Authentication not working how to fix this?

I have attached the screenshot of error[Click Here Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VdmF.jpg)
**Error got: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.**

***Note: its working on debug APK.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Android Device Verification first.
For steps on how to do that check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).